# JS window.close doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Code snippet to make make popup window:

```
<script>
function about() {
window.open( "/aboutserver.html", "_blank", 
"location=no, titlebar=no, status = no, height = 650, width = 300, resizable = no, location=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no");
}
</script>
<a href="#" onClick="about()">Server Info</a> <br>
```

Here is the code of the actual popup window:

```
<div align="center"><html><body><h1>Info</h1></div>
<br>Provides:<br><br><br>
blah blah etc
<script>
function close(){
window.self.close();
}
</script>
<button onClick=close()>Close</button>
```

I have also tried window.close(); and window.close('aboutserver.html')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding the global `close` function. You should be getting a stack overflow error from the function trying to call itself.

You can just remove your custom `close` function and just call the global `close()` directly, or rename your function to something like `closeWin`

Comment: Funny, I couldn't get it to work in Chrome or FF :) http://jsfiddle.net/6KXz9/ It's probably something about jsfiddle and different sub-domains